# if statement inside for loop prints two times

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def toChars(s):
    s = s.lower()
    letters = ""
    for c in s:
        if c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            letters = letters + c
            print(letters)
    return letters


print(toChars("Op2lk"))

o
op
opl
oplk
oplk
```

This function converts all letters to lowercase and removes all non letters. I added a print fuction to see how this code works exactly. As you can see above it prints "oplk" twice. Why is that ?

2nd part of the question, ignore the first part.

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    """Assumes s is a str
        Returns True if the letters in s form a palindrome;
        False otherwise. Non-letters and capitalization are ignored."""
    def toChars(s):
        s = s.lower()
        letters = ''
        for c in s:
            if c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
                letters = letters + c
        return letters
    def isPal(s):
        print (' isPal called with', s)
        if len(s) <= 1:
            print (' About to return True from base case')
            return True
        else:
            answer = s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])
            print(' About to return', answer, 'for', s)
            return answer
        
    return isPal(toChars(s))

isPalindrome("Op2lk")
isPalindrome("Oppo")
```

Outputs,

```
isPal called with oplk
 About to return False for oplk

isPal called with oppo
 isPal called with pp
 isPal called with 
 About to return True from base case
 About to return True for pp
 About to return True for oppo
```

Why return statements which inside the isPal function doesn't print anything  ?

Comment: It prints twice because the function prints letters each time and then you also print the return value, which is the last value of `letters`.

Comment: When you remove the `print(letters)` from the function, you'll just get one output.

Comment: That's just temporary so you can see how it works, don't worry about the duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you use `print(toChars("Op2lk"))` that's second `oplk` is the output of that

if you want one line solution, just in case

```
def toChars(s):
    return ''.join(list(filter(lambda x : ord(x) in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1), s.lower())))

print(toChars("Op2lk"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using "stringtes".lower() ?

Also, you have printed the output and the result, just remove the print inside the function:

```
def toChars(s):
    s = s.lower()
    letters = ""
    for c in s:
        if c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            letters = letters + c
    return letters


print(toChars("Op2lk"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are using return after `print`.
When `for` clause ended, it returns `letters` variable. So it returns the completed statement twice.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it prints normally in the loop, and then you print the returned letters.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement inside the `for` loop is NOT printing two times. The twice repetition of "oplk" is due to

1. the print statement inside the method, which is inside if statement.
2. the print statement outside the method i.e print(toChars("Op2lk")) in which you are printing the returned value

Answer (score 0):

It printed twice because your printed the letters in the function already, and then you return the letters and printed outside of the function again.